# Google bubble chart padding

Tags: javascript, charts, padding

Having an issue where the bubble chart is running off of the axis using a google bubble chart.

Any idea how to either add spacing, or change the axis scale to accomodate the extra space?

You can see an example of what I am talking about here:
http://jsfiddle.net/k77bp25g/2/

```
function drawSeriesChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['ID', 'Life Expectancy', 'Fertility Rate', 'Region',     'Population'],
    ['CAN',    0,              1.67,      'North America',  933739900],
    ['DEU',    79.84,              1.36,      'Europe',         933739900]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Correlation between life expectancy, fertility rate and population of some world countries (2010)',
    hAxis: {title: 'Life Expectancy'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Fertility Rate'},
    bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: you might try some thing like this `function ex(){chart.stye="padding:100px;";` or try adding in the `<style>` tag and change the styles there, also if you can try setting each data point with a related HTML tag it might make things a little simpler

Comment: Check this forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/WBOq--U2C7E

Comment: I tried adding in the chart.style right before it draws but it looks like it didn't change the padding- im not sure you can add the padding on each bubble in google charts. It seems somewhat limited.